# Meaning of components in merTools::predictInterval

Tags: r, predict, lme4

It's not completely clear to me what the `merTools::predictInterval` function exactly predicts for each component when the `which` option is set to `which = 'all'`. For example,

```
library(lme4)
library(merTools)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)
pred <- predictInterval(fm1, which = 'all')
pred[pred$obs == 1,]
```

returns

```
      effect      fit      upr        lwr obs
1   combined 293.6893 335.0569 249.310016   1
181  Subject  40.6980  82.8388  -4.490277   1
361    fixed 251.2517 292.0853 212.230277   1
```

I assumed that the fit for the fixed effect and the fit for the random effect Subject would add up to the fit for the combined effect. However, I get:

```
> sum(pred[pred$obs == 1 & pred$effect %in% c('fixed','Subject'),]$fit)
[1] 291.9497
```

What am I interpreting wrongly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that `predictInterval` is simulating prediction intervals by drawing from the posterior distribution. The way it presents the components is the result of independent draws for the random, fixed, and combined effects. So while logically they should add up, with measurement error and the variance in the effects themselves, with a finite number of simulations the means or medians of those distributions will not line up to sum to the combined effect.

You can increase `n.sims` to a very large number (~5000, 10,000) and this gap will be smaller.

But the key issue is that each of those rows is the result of independent draws from the posterior.